# How to efficiently partition a sorted List<double> values

Tags: c#, list, partitioning

I have a List of doubles, which may contain duplicate values and is sorted in ascending order, that needs to be split into X partitions (where X is provided by the user) such that:

1. Any duplicate values fall within the same partition
2. The partitions, to the extent possible, contain the same number of elements; and
3. The original order of the values is preserved (the values are actually associated with keys to transactions that have to be processed sequentially).

Given the requirement to keep duplicate values in the same partition, is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: It might help if you're able to provide more details around what you're trying to achieve.  Why do you want to 'partition' this list of values?  What sort of range is X?  How large is the dataset?

Comment: The goal is to determine quantiles (subject to the restriction on duplicate values being in the same partition) for analysis and processing of datasets that often contain millions of double values from Double.MinValue to Double.MaxValue.

Comment: So far, I've tried drinking more coffee... it hasn't helped.  This still seems deceptively complicated.  I'm confident a clustering style approach will work: allocate X ranges respecting the duplicates rule, calculate the sum of variances from the target range size, repeatedly swap the first/last "flock" of numbers between ranges until the sum of variances is minimized.  In lieu of a better idea from a StackOverflow friend, that's the plan.

Comment: Hmm, this is outside my statistics knowledge (which is admittedly very limited), but from the sounds of it, you could use a LINQ expression to group by discrete values, keeping a count of instances of values.  Split the discrete values, then rebuild the data set as the last step.

Comment: It depends on your data. The clustering approach is probably the best way of doing this, moving the ends of each partition to encapsulate flocks and balance partition sizes. But if the size of the duplicate flocks will be significant (statistically or otherwise), then you'll definitely want to note the start and end positions of large flocks during construction or sorting of the initial list (LINQ may be fine, but personally I would keep everything in an explicitly contiguous collection, calculate the desired ranges, then just use `List.CopyRange` or `Array.Copy` or w.e at the end).

Comment: Ignoring the case where the data is at odds with the request e.g. asked for two quantiles and the data consists of only values containing ones,  the "right" answer is any set of quantiles such that the sum of the variances from the target size of the intervals they delineate is minimized. The number of partitions "X" is specified by the user.

Comment: if the number of duplicates > x, then whats the expected output?

Comment: The partition sizes need to be as close to equal as the data permits regardless of the impact on execution time otherwise it skews any analysis of the data.  @Gauravsa, I'm not sure what you're asking?  If the number of unique values in the dataset is less than X, it will be handled as a special case and fewer partitions will be created accordingly.

Comment: The datasets will often contain millions of double values.

Comment: What are the consequences of the partitions not having the same size of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it isn't bad form to answer my own question, here's the approach I ended up going with:

1) Calculate the "ideal" partition size: `valuesCount / numPartitions`
2) The first partition begins at index 0
3) Calculate successive potential break point indexes as:
    `lastBreakIndex + (unallocatedValuesCount / remainingPartitions)`
4) A break point has to fall on the first occurrence of a value.  If it doesn't, adjust the breakpoint to the first occurrence of a value or to the next value, whichever is closer.
5) Use the summed squared deviation from the ideal size of each partition as a quality metric.
6) As each additional breakpoint is added, try successively adjusting each prior breakpoint by moving it one "value change" forward and backward and recalculating the quality metric.  If the metric is lower, keep the change and try again.

Some special case checking needs to be done e.g. less value breaks than requested partitions.  There may also be edge cases I haven't considered.  But, this seems to quickly give reasonable results against the data sets I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't have any smartness like group related one together:

Suppose, List have length L.

```
X = 3; Chunk Size = X;
data1 = Take[data, Chunk Size]
data2 = Skip chunk size members and take next X members;
repeat; 

public static IEnumerable<List<List<double>>>  GetSubList()
{
    List<double> values = new List<double> { 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 20.0, 21.0 };
    List<List<double>> subPartition = new List<List<double>>();

    var X = 2;
    int chunkSize = X;
    int length = values.Count;

    if (length < X)
    {
       subPartition.Add(values);
       yield return subPartition;
       yield break;
    }

    subPartition.Add(values.Take(chunkSize).ToList());
    while (values.Skip(chunkSize).Any())
    {
        subPartition.Add(values.Skip(chunkSize).Take(X).ToList());
        chunkSize += X;
    }

    yield return subPartition;
}
```

Comment: thanks!  That looks like a reasonable way to partition data.  In my case, I know the count of values ahead of time so knowing I need count/partitions values is trivial.  It's the seemingly simple rule that duplicates have to be in the same partition and that partitions have to be as close to the same size as each other as possible that complicates things.

Comment: Respectfully, I appreciate the response.  But, if I just had to partition the data I'd probably do something like:
 <code>
List<Tuple<int, int>> partitions = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
double partitionSize = itemsCount / parts;
for( int i=0; i < parts; i++ )
{   partitions.Add(new Tuple<int, int>( (int) (i * partitionSize), (int) (( i + 1 ) * partitionSize ) - 1) );
}
</code>

To store partition indicies into the existing List (more likely, I'd just store the index of the start of a partition).  I don't think your solution addresses the real complexity which is dealing with dupes.